Where can I find my init.ora file in Oracle 19c?
I need to find what the SMTP_OUT_SERVER parameter is set as for a database that uses UTL_MAIL. But I can't find where the init.ora file is present. The oracle version is 19c.
I tried checking what the ORACLE_HOME variable points to, but it hasn't been set. I tried running show parameter file which returned Show parameters query failed. Is there another way to find my init.ora file or is it not present in oracle 19c? Also is there a way to find the SMTP_OUT_SERVER value without the init.ora file? Thanks.
Edit:
I tried this Opposite of Oracle "ALTER SYSTEM SET" Command to try and get the smtp_out_server value, but instead get this.
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"


It seems the user you are connected as doesn't have privileges to query v$parameter, which is what show parameters is looking at under the hood; if you did you could show parameters smtp_out_server directly. You may need to ask your DBA to get the information for you.

Also regarding the init.ora... you're using the SQL Developer client, and that file is on the database server. It sounds like that it a different machine, and only the DBAs may/should be able to access that anyway.

Thanks for your answer @AlexPoole . I was confused about it. It is indeed in a different machine.
